# Is there a way to make village info mod work on vanilla Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

I have downloaded and installed the village info mod. It works when I tested it in a single player world. However, when I tested logging in to my own Minecraft server the mod does not display any info about the village when I press F3.

Is there a way to see the village info when running a multiplayer server? Ideally so that anyone with the modded client can see the village info. Have I made a mistake somewhere and it works for other people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little out of the loop when it comes to Minecraft modding, but a quick look at the docs for [Village Info](http://chunkbase.com/mods/village-info) state that:

Vanilla Mod does not work in SMP.

However the Forge Mod can support SMP if it's also installed on the server as well (forge server). So it won't work with a vanilla server I'm afraid.

Note also that this appears to only work in the 1.6 version [according to the Minecraft Forum announcement post.](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/1281986-village-info):

> Edit: SMP support is currently on hold, but might return in the future. Only the 1.6 version supports it.

Comment: I guess I will have to copy the world from the server onto my machine and maybe I can find the info there.